# ionic plugin for accessing local machines

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, mdns

I am trying to access .local machine using a hybrid app built on ionic framework. Whereas it works fine with simulator and browser in iOS devices, it doesn't work on android app or browser within android. Access via IP address works fine.

Is there an ionic/cordova plugin for accessing local machines (with .local domain)?

Comment: with cordova 5.0.0 - you need cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Doesn't seems to work. Also when I explore http://website.local/ on browser on android, i get **"The server at http://website.local/ can't be found, because DNS lookup failed" error.**  However this works on Safari.